# How to print screen in Remote Desktop Client (RDS) on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop

I'm using version 2.1.0 of Remote Desktop Client on my MacBook Pro with [Mac OS X Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (version 10.6). How do I use the `fn` or `cmd` call to simulate a print screen on the remote system?

Comment: @PeterMortensen RDS?

Comment: Please check the @user1570136, that's the best answer which one can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> replaces <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to “tab” through running applications in the RDP window.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> takes a screen print of the remote desktop (just like using <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> on a local computer).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad -</kbd> takes a screen print of the active window inside the RDP window (just like using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> on the desktop).

Comment: Nope - none of those work in my session. `alt + tab` replace `cmd + tab` and the other two just don't do anything noticeable. I ended up just running `cmd + shift + 4` and emailed the screenshot from one session to the other, but there must be a better way. My setup is OSX --RDC--> Win 7 VM.

Comment: @mjb You don't have a numeric key pad on your Macbook Pro. Did you connect a full size keyboard to test this?

Comment: I did not - didn't realize that's what your parenthetical comment implied. Let me give it a go. In the meantime, any ways around it on the straight keyboard?

Comment: of course mjb doesn't have a numeric keyboard on his macbook pro. Connecting a full size keyboard doesn't answer the question as asked: "How do I use the fn or cmd call to simulate a print screen on the remote system?"

Comment: Note - there is no Alt key on a Mac keyboard.

Comment: @GregBrown On my olderish MBP if you look at `option` I see `alt` right above it!

Answer (score 23):

Here's an **alternative solution** to Oliver's answer for those that have those "half" mac keyboards without number pads,

From within the RDP Windows screen, Start > All Programs > Accessories > Ease of Use > On-Screen Keyboard.

This onscreen keyboard has all of the keys you need including Print Screen.

Comment: That's a killer solution friend, works like charm without getting into all the key combinations on MAC.

Comment: This is the only way I could get this to work from my Retina MacBook Pro using Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.x to Windows 7/8/Vista/XP sessions. It even works with `Alt + PrtSc` to take a snapshot of the current window.

Comment: How does this work if you want to take a screen shot of the screen? The on-screen keyboard covers half of the screen? How do I press PrtScrn on the on-screen keyboard without actually having the on-screen keyboard visible?

Comment: You can move the on-screen keyboard pretty far off to the left. Not ideal, but you can probably grab whatever you are trying to grab.

Answer (score 4):

**Warning: This may close the current application for some users**

I believe what you're looking for is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.  This gives me a "print screen" command inside the Windows RDP session to trigger application like SnagIt.

Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> gives you the straight function keys inside the RDP session, or at least this has worked for my MBP keyboard.

Comment: This is the only answer that work for me. Thank you

Comment: Ha, without thinking I hit this, and it closed my window. Option is also Alt, so it's just hitting Alt + F4

Comment: So why does this joke answer have any upvotes? Alt-F4 just closes your current application in Windows.

Comment: I'm assuming putting `Fn` before `Option / Alt` is intended to change the behavior of the key?  Either way, this didn't work for me at all.  It neither initiated a `PrntScrn` nor closed any window.  It did... nothing.

Answer (score 3):

if you click on the RDC menu at top of screen on OSX,  click on preferences,  then keyboard,  you should have a Mac shortcut of option f4 (default)  i actually remapped mine to option 1 (as i couldn't get option f4 to work on the standard bluetooth keyboard,  but obviously you can map to whatever you like

Comment: opt+f4 works for me on a macbook pro under mountain lion

Answer (score 3):

Easy way: PDF what you want a shot of then use "take a snapshot" from the pdf and just hit paste where you need it.  Saves it to the PC clipboard thru your mac.

Your welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may find that your RDS admin has provided a separate snipping tool to provide this function - my session certainly has this. Checking the app, it seems to be part of the Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard server release.

Comment: Upvoting.  This works better than every other solution, for me.  The onscreen keyboard does work but I was only able to get it to take a fullscreen capture, which includes the OSK itself.  Start > "Snipping Tool", is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Command+Space <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (Windows+Space <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> when plugging a PC keyboard).  Alternatively, move the mouse to the top of the screen to bring up the MacOS system ribbon (Mojave here) and click the looking glass icon  on the right.  Observe the transparent input field in the middle of the screen.
2. Type "screenshot" and click the "screenshot.app" result.  The screenshot app will launch, offering to select the screen area to snapshot.
3. The shutter button resides in the bottom of the screen, in a transparent block of large icons.

Comment: No Windows key on a Mac keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, @GregBrown, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Faster alternative solution / remote machine is Win7: on remote machine, open Start menu (hit cmd on Mac keyboard), type "osk" (wihout quotes), make sure "osk.exe" is highlighted, hit Enter on Mac keyboard. (osk.exe = On Screen Keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

In the Citrix remote session on a mac, move your mouse to the top of the screen. The Citrix menu bar will drop down.
Click in this order,

Devices->Keyboard->Send Key->Print Screen

If you use the windows on screen keyboard as in a previous answer it will include a photo of the keyboard. If you do the citrix menu option it just takes the entire screen the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative is the following.

If you have the *Send to OneNote tool* (part of MS Office) running on your remote Windows machine, then an easy solution is to hit `COMMAND`+`S`, select the region you would like to copy and subsequently click `Copy to Clipboard`.

This has the benefit of selecting only a part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

On my wired Apple-Keyboard, i can use F13 as an equivalent to the PrintScreen-Key on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with this since some time on my Mac with a citrix client opening my work Windows machine.

Finally figured a solution that works for apps like Snagit.

Open the settings/preferences of the screen-capture app (in my case Snagit), and change the hotkey.

I changed it to F1. You can use any hotkey of your choice.

And now the print-screen works marvellously on my Windows remote desktop from my Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

Windows screenshots can also be done with `Shift`+`Windows Key`+`S`.